# How to hide the double-pattern of a map obtained from the raster calculator in ArcGIS?

Tags: model, calculator, arcgis, raster

I am currently working on a map model in ArcGIS and I use 3 maps as predictors: DEM, Slope and TDD (all 5 m resolution). However, TDD was obtained from a multiplication of snow persistence map (250 m resolution but resampled to 5 m) and temperatures map (5 m resolution). This probably is the cause of the problem I get in the final map: even if I resampled every predictor, the final map still shows the pattern of the snow persistence map showed below.
Is there a solution to hide this pattern?

[image: Final model map]

Answer (score 0):

Even though your *raster* is resampled to 5m cells, it is still using *data* with 250m resolution. The 5m resolution TDD would visibly appear to be identical to the 250m resolution.

Rather than *resampling* the raster, you need to *interpolate* to get a finer resolution than the source data. (Convert from raster to points, interpolate the points into a 5m resolution raster) However, be aware that [this can be very prone to error and inaccuracy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29443/interpolating-and-infilling-a-raster-from-5km-pixels-to-100m-pixels-in-arcmap-10). Whether that is acceptable or not for your particular analysis is up to you.